# Oracle - how to efficiently do Hierarchical Queries

Tags: java, oracle

I have a table in which below two column define the person and mgr relationship. If I have to fetch all people belong to a specific manager and all it's indirect reportee, what will be the best approach ?

Also how to do it specific to some level, for example fetch all users of specific personid upto level 2 or n etc

```
PERSONID REPORTTO_PERSONID
2              1
3              1
4              1
5              1
6              4
7              4
8              7
9              2
```

Comment: Are you looking for plsql or java code?

Comment: There is no "personid = 1" in your example

Comment: that is my bad...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find recursively all people reporting to the personid = 2

The `level` column denotes the relative distance to the row that was specified in the `start with` condition. Not the overall level in the hierarchy.

```
select *
from (
  select personid, 
         reportto_personid, 
         level as lvl
  from the_table
  start with personid = 2
  connect by prior personid = reportto_personid
) t 
where lvl <= 2;
```

More details [are in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm#i2053935) and all the questions listed on the right side of this page.

Comment: thanks for this example looks promising to me what about the n level?